# "db.model(...).whereIn is not a function" for db.Model(...).whereIn()

Tags: node.js, knex.js

I need to alter a legacy portion of my knex to dynamically accept a single value or array.

I don't want to alter the existing query as other portions of the app rely on it.

Adding `ids instanceof Array || (ids = [ids]);` and changing `where` to `whereIn`, I thought I could get one or many return values, but instead I get error

> Unhandled rejection TypeError: db.model(...).whereIn is not a function

This works when I pass a single value to a `where` clause, but not with `whereIn`, why is that?

In `User` Model:

```
  byId: function(ids) {
    ids instanceof Array || (ids = [ids]);
    return db.knex('User')
      .whereIn('id', ids)
      .fetch()
      .then(function(users) {
        return users.toJSON();
      });
  },
```

Original (working):

```
  byId: function(id) {
    return db.knex('User')
      .where('id', id)
      .fetch()
      .then(function(user) {
        return user.toJSON();
      });
  },
```

---

**Note**: using `db.knex.select().from('tablename')` to select the model **works**, but directly using `db.knex('ModelName')` does not. Why?

```
  byIds: function(ids) {
    ids instanceof Array || (ids = [ids]);
    return db.knex.select('*')
      .from('users')
      .whereIn('id', ids);
  },
```

Comment: what is the output of console.log(ids)?

Answer (score 0):

this cannot work`.whereIn('id', ids)` is Shorthand for .where('id', 'in', obj) must be a array. check this line  ids instanceof Array || (ids = [ids]);
try a dummy array first: `[4, 5, 6]`